# Display DialogFragment almost full screen within an AppCompatActivity but still keep the toolbar visible

Tags: android, themes, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I'm trying to figure a style for a `DialogFragment` in order to display it almost full screen within an `Activity`, but not to cover the toolbar.

I've been using the following style which gives me a full screen dialog, but I'm not able to figure out what parameters I should set in order to keep the `Toolbar` visible:

**styles xml:**

```
   <style name="Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
      <item name="windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: Do u want to show tool bar or not ?

Comment: @Adrian means you need to keep activity toolbar visible while opening a full-screen dialog?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur Almoust full screen, means its below the toolbar

Comment: @Adrian but, you are not able to use activity toolbar while dialog fragment is opened.

Comment: @ Kannan panneer selvam I want to show the toolbar, then below the toolbar have the dialog fragment take all the remaining space